# simplifying the contents of an input using the javascript math system

Tags: javascript, html, math

This obviuosly works perfectly:`<script>alert(5*8-4)</script>`

but i need to solve whatever someone puts inside an input box.

Heres what I thought of doing:  I would get the value of the input, into a variable. then I would use

```
document.write("<script>alert("+theinputvalue+")<script>");
```

or do this:

```
var string="<script>alert("+theinputvalue+")<script>";document.write(string);
```

but nothing works.

Is it even possible to do this? if not, tell my what simple other system I could use.

eventually, I will use it to graph lines like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
for(var x=-100; x<100; x=x+.2){
    y = .1*(x*x)
    ctx.fillRect(x+50, -1*y+50, 2, 2);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KGgq4/

Comment: Are you trying to specify the whole equation (something like "y = 2x^2 + 6") in the input or just some coefficients?

Comment: yup thats what i am doing. trying to have an input containing x and everything else to solve

Comment: The demo for Jison, a JS parser generator, is a calculator.  Might be worth a look http://zaach.github.io/jison/demos/calc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval('5*8-4')
```

will result in 36

Comment: true however sanitizing user input should always be a priority. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any library that is doing that (this doesn't mean that there are no such it simply means I never actually needed that) but what you should end up doing is to build an automata that will parse input string and transform it to a proper graph with proper transformations. This is not very easy topic and if you want to go this route you should start reading on arithmetic expressions parsing algorithms (sorry I do not have any solution in place).

Or you can cheat and define types of equations that will be selected by user. Once user selects type of equation you should be able show user inputs where user will be able to select coefficients. You can read those coefficients into different variables and apply transformations in your draw procedure (For example if user will select type sin(x) you know that general equation has following formula: y = k*sin(a*x + b) + c. So once it is selected you can allow user to enter k, a, b, c and based on that input calculate appropriate locations of points for your graph.)

Well, third solution could involve "eval ", but usually you should avoid eval at any cost (B/c it is straight forward JavaScript injection which may be an OK for this case but may get you in trouble later in your life. ).

Comment: I used eval(), found it much easier. I don't really need something so complex, but thanks, I looked into it and it looks nice

Answer (score 0):

You can use [math.js](http://mathjs.org/), which comes with an advanced expression parser. It supports definition of variables and functions.

```
// create an instance of math.js
var math = mathjs();

// evaluate an expression
math.eval('5*8-4'); // 36

// user defined function (returns a native JavaScript function)
var f = math.eval('f(x) = 2*x^2 + 6');

// use the function (for graphing or something) 
f(2); // 14
```

Comment: I used eval(), found it much easier. I don't really need something so complex, but thanks, I looked into it and it looks nice